# Device node getting created but device driver not getting linked

Tags: linux, char, kernel, driver, device

I have written a simple device driver. Only loading the module my device file is getting created. But when my application tries to open the device file I am getting an error `-1 (operation not permitted)`. When I have tried to look at device characteristics by executing the command:

```
 $udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/char/<devname>
```

I get the output:

```
KERNEL=="<devname>"
SUBSYSTEM=="char" 
DRIVER==" "
```

So apparently my device node is not getting linked to the device driver.

Can anybody please help me out with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the permissions on the device node udev created?

Udev manages the permissions of those device nodes, and unless you're running as root it's quite likely you're not allowed to read/write from/to the device node.

**Edit**

If you're running as root the permissions on the device node won't be a factor. Please show us the content of /proc/devices, the output of `ls -la /dev/my-device-node` and *your code*.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I am running as a root user. The permission of the device node created is crw-rw---- . How should I change the permission without using chmod.

Comment: What could be the reason when I am using udevadm info for my device getting the driver feild empty i.e " ".